# How to configure async apache http client 5 to use SOCKS proxy?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to configure async http client to use SOCKS proxy. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22960881/4767134) is the answer for sync http client. I don't know how to set `ConnectionSocketFactory` to async http client. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's even easier than in sync http client:

```
HttpAsyncClients.custom()
        .setIOReactorConfig(
            IOReactorConfig.custom()
                .setSocksProxyAddress(InetSocketAddress("mysockshost", 1234))
                .build()
        )
        .build()
```